I am trying to run Mask-RCNN using the coco h5 parameter file. I get a mismatch between the architecture and the h5 file
I get the following error message:
ValueError: Layer #389 (named "mrcnn_bbox_fc"), weight <tf.Variable 'mrcnn_bbox_fc/kernel:0' shape=(1024, 4) dtype=float32> has shape (1024, 4), but the saved weight has shape (1024, 324)
How can I get a matching parameter file or change the architecture?
I have tried to find an appropriate parameter file.

Hi @Uri.l I had this error too. This error is related to version incompatibilities. What is your Python and tensorflow version ?
